# UIAlertController does not disable controls of its presenter UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I am inside a child UIViewController. I present a UIAlertController using the following code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default Style", message: "A standard alert.", preferredStyle: .alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in

}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)
self?.present(alertController, animated: true)
```

The problem is that when the alert is presented, I can still tap and edit the controls of the presenter view controller.

What changed the default behavior of blocking the parent (presenter) view controller when presenting the alert?

Comment: Well, obviously it's the fact that you are "inside a child UIViewController". You may not have configured that correctly. On the other hand, I would suggest that maybe you should not be presenting the alert from the _child_, so maybe presenting from the _parent_ would just fix it?

Comment: whenever the alert controller is presented at that time no other controller is accessable. What you want to achieve? please add some image or video for exact idea.